# TypeDoc totally ignores top-level comments React TS

Tags: reactjs, typedoc

TypeDoc totally ignores top-level comments in my functional component index file. Same story if comment in a component file, and doc generates directly for it. I just started to use TypeDoc for my React project, could somebody explain what's wrong?

Without `typedoc-plugin-markdown` in modules.html it shows only params and their description (!only if comment upper imports!), but still ignores other comments: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOSts.png

If a comment is lower than imports it will be ignored totally.

index.ts

```
/**
 * @module LogoSafeComponent
 * # This is a comment!!!
 * ## This is a comment 2!!!
 * ## This is a comment 3!!!
 * @param classNameCustom - custom styling class name
 * @param isSmall - img size
 * @module
 */

/** ignore this comment */
export * from "./LogoSafe";
```

modules.md output

```
[safe-app](README.md) / Exports

# some-app

## Table of contents

### Functions

- [LogoSafeComponent](modules.md#logosafecomponent)

## Functions

### LogoSafeComponent

▸ **LogoSafeComponent**(`__namedParameters`): `ReactElement`<`any`, `string` \| `JSXElementConstructor`<`any`\>\>

#### Parameters

| Name                                 | Type      |
| :----------------------------------- | :-------- |
| `__namedParameters`                  | `Object`  |
| `__namedParameters.classNameCustom?` | `string`  |
| `__namedParameters.isSmall?`         | `boolean` |

#### Returns

`ReactElement`<`any`, `string` \| `JSXElementConstructor`<`any`\>\>

#### Defined in

[LogoSafe.tsx:13](https://github.com/SomeAppOfficial/chrome-extension/blob/efc774c/src/components/LogoSafe/LogoSafe.tsx#L13)
```

typedoc.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2017",
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "tsx": "react",
    "noEmit": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "entryPoints": ["src/components/LogoSafe/index.ts"],
  "$schema": "https://typedoc.org/schema.json",
  "out": "type-doc",
  "excludePrivate": true
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "ESNext",
    "types": ["vite/client", "@types/chrome"]
  },
  "include": [
    "src",
    "vite.config.ts",
    "rollup.extensions.js",
    "functions/src",
    "adapters"
  ]
}
```

If I highlit my component in code and comment in my module is lower than imports, the documentation looks as expected, but in generated  module.html this data will not be displayed in this case:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fq01y.png

Actually, I expect something the same (data structure and content) in my .md output or module.html.
I want to see my comments when highlighting components in my code and in my generated docs.

Comment: No need for the angular tag on this question, as it pertains to React and TypeDoc

Comment: Sorry, accidentally added.

Comment: Answered in [TypeStrong/typedoc#2003](https://github.com/TypeStrong/typedoc/issues/2003)